# In WP7, can I render a bitmap on-the-fly and use it as the Tile background?

Tags: windows-phone-7, bitmap, tile

I know that in Mango, we can update the Tile's background locally.
But "StandardTileData.BackgroundImage" is of the type Uri, does this mean I have to use an Image that was added to the project's resource?
Or can I render a bitmap on-the-fly and use it as the Tile background?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked but I would assume that you can create an image in "on-the-fly", save it to Isolated Storage and then set the source of the tile image to be a relative URI which points into IsolatedStorage.

Comment: Is "a relative URI which points into IsolatedStorage" possible? I googled, but did not find anything.